# How to hook script to another page? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write addition to some website. I don't have access to source code of this web page. This script will be only facilitation (show more info from cookies) and work on client-site. I won't change behavior of page.

When I load website, I should just run a script. How I can do that?

Comment: What browser are you using? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Thanks. Its answer to my question so you should add post and delete comment, and get some points :)

Comment: Thanks! Hope you solved your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom javascript code to a page you do not own, use a browser extention like [Tamper Monkey for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), or [greeseMonkey for firefox](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey)

This will allow custom code to be run by your browser on pages you specify, note only you will see these changes.